# Python: How to use Gtk.ListBox.selected_foreach ()?

Tags: python, foreach, gtk

I would like to delete a specific row in a Gtk.ListBox.

I am working with Python and Gtk. I have a Gtk.ListBox containing Gtk.ListBoxRow children. Each row has a label. I would like to delete for example the row with the "test" label. To do so I would like to browse the Gtk.ListBox and for each rows, read the label and determine if it is equal to "test". If it is then the row should be deleted. To do so I thought about selecting all the rows of my box and then use the selected_foreach function to get the label of the row but I am a bit confused on how to use this function.

```py
class List(Gtk.ListBox):
     def __init__(self,builder,object):
          self.size = 0
          self.users_list_box = self.builder.get_object(object)

     def test(self,chemin,iter,donnees)
          print("This is a test")

class ABox(Gtk.VBox):
     def __init__(self,builder):
          self.list = List(self.builder,"list")

     def myfunction():

          self.list.users_list_box.select_all()
          self.list.users_list_box.selected_foreach(self.list.test)
```

I expected the message "This is a test" to be printed as many times as I have rows in my list box but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GtkListBox is a subclass of GtkContainer, that's why you can just iterate over all rows with [Gtk.Container.foreach](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Container.html#Gtk.Container.foreach). GtkListBox [consists](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/ListBox.html#Gtk.ListBox) of 
GtkListBoxRows, which are subclasses of GtkBin. You can use [Gtk.Bin.get_child](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/ListBox.html#Gtk.ListBox) to get access to the widget inside GtkListBoxRow. After that you can [Gtk.Container.remove](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Container.html#Gtk.Container.remove) unwanted Row.